# Настройка триггера мониторинга лога в Zabbix

Tags: linux, zabbix

Имеется файл лога, в нормальном виде он имеет нулевое значение. В случае нештатной ситуации скрипт сортирует данные из лога программы и пишет в данный лог на который, в свою очередь, натравлен Zabbix. При возврате к штатному состоянию лог очищается. Как сделать триггер, который срабатывал бы в момент, когда в логе появляются строки, и отключал алерт, когда лог очищался.
Ключ выглядит следующим образом:

```
log[/var/log/ch.log]
```